# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/',array('uses'=>'student@index'));
Route::get('/view',array('uses'=>'student@view'));
Route::post('/save',array('uses'=>'student@save'));
```

This is the code and I am working on form and when I submit the form, it shows this error:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 201:

**student.php**

```
class student extends Controller  {

    public function index()
     {   
         //return 'hello world';

        return \View::make('student.index');
      }
          public function view()
     {
        return \View::make('student.view');
      }

          public function save()
     {
        //return \View::make('student.view');

        $validation= array(
                      'first_name'=>'required',

                      'email'=>'required'

                          );
        $v1=validator::make(Input::all(),$validation);
        if( $v1->fails())
        {
        return Redirect::to('view')->withErrors($v1);
        }
        else
        { $poststudent=Input::all();
          $data = array('first_name'=>$poststudent['first_name'],
                         'last_name'=>$poststudent['last_name'],
                         'email'=>$poststudent['email'],
                         'interested'=>$poststudent['interested'], 
                         'skills'=>$poststudent['skills']);

        $check=0;
        $check=DB::table('students')->insert($data);

        if($check > 0)
        {
        return Redirect::to('/');
        }
        else
        {
        return Redirect::to('/view');
        }

        }



      }

        }
```

Form is like this:

```
<form action="<?=URL::to('/save')?>" methed="POST">
<div class="form-group">
 <label for= "first_name"> FIRST NAME </label>
<input name="FIRST NAME" type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="first       name"/>
</div>
```

I am stuck here.

Comment: Have you checked to ensure that the `<form>` is rendered with a `/save` route? Have you checked the routes file is indeed run? Maybe it is in the wrong place.

Comment: Aha! `methed` is a misspelling - should be `method`. Also your `<input />` unique `id` has spaces in it, which is invalid.

Comment: thankew brother. it works... great eye... method was mispelled

Comment: man it shows now... what should i do

Comment: TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:

Comment: I don't use Laravel, but I imagine you need to render a CSRF token inside your form. What does the documentation say?

Comment: If you're not using Laravel's form builder, you have to include the CSRF token yourself. See this entry on [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-51-csrf-token)

Comment: FatalErrorException in student.php line 32:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found

Comment: what should i do of this???

Comment: Make sure you `use` the `Input` facade in your controller. Place `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;` at the top of your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to configure your allowed HTTP methods in `httpd.conf` if you are on Apache server.

Add this line into your `httpd.conf` the `<Directory XXXX>` tag:

```
AllowMethods GET POST OPTIONS
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Well, it's a type of error sent by the server to your laravel application, so the Laravel raises an exception in order to not get blocked,

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to name the routes: see my reply here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47147452/5550606
2. Please put the {{ csrf_field() }} right after the `<form>`... tag. Or you will get a TokenMissmatch exception.