# Laravel Error: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php

Tags: laravel-5

Having creating a code for Excel upload I am getting the below mentioned error...

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php

The codes written in VIEW is

views/items/items

```
  @extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="row">
<form action="{{route('items.import')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                {{csrf_field()}}
                <input type="file" name="imported-file"/>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Import</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
         <!-- <button class="btn btn-success">Export</button> -->
        </div>
      </div>

    @endsection
```

The codes written in route.php is...

```
Route::get('/items', 'ItemController@index');

Route::post('/items/import',[ 'as' => 'items.import', 'uses' => 'ItemController@import']);
```

ItemController.ASPX

```
 public function index()
    {
      return view('items.items');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
public function import(Request $request)
    {
      if($request->file('imported-file'))
      {
                $path = $request->file('imported-file')->getRealPath();
                $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {
            })->get();

            if(!empty($data) && $data->count())
      {
        $data = $data->toArray();
        for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
        {
          $dataImported[] = $data[$i];
        }
            }
      Inventory::insert($dataImported);
        }
        return back();
  }
```

Can anyone please help me what am missing in my coding that outputs the error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code instead of yours:

```
Route::post('/items/import',[ 'as' => 'items/import', 'uses' => 'ItemController@import']);
```

The trick is - the route needs to be named.
To avoid future confusion, it's better to name it as "items.import", so later you can identify for yourself that this is a "name" of a route.
So the final code would be:

```
Route::post('/items/import',[ 'as' => 'items.import', 'uses' => 'ItemController@import']);
```

and in blade template u call it like that:

```
<form action="{{route('items.import')}}"...
```

Comment: You have a typo. It'd be `route('items.import')`.

Comment: @fubar Tnx! Fixed!

Comment: @sandcode...thanks but am getting this error now...NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php

Comment: @user3305327 Please show your new web.php and the form tag, maybe there is a typo somewhere

Comment: @sandcode...thanks for your time...I have just edited my post with the full codes.

Comment: oh i assumed you had a newer version of laravel

Try this:
`<form action="{{ URL::to('items/import') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

and in routes.php


`Route::post('/items/import', 'ItemController@import');`

Comment: @sandcode...now am getting this error...MethodNotAllowedHttpException, FYI...am follwoing this tutorials...https://appdividend.com/2017/06/12/import-export-data-csv-excel-laravel-5-4/

Comment: @sandcode...okies I have figured out the issue and resolved it. its actually the size of the excel which I was trying to upload. Upto 5MB, its getting uploaded but the file size is 12MB so its getting failed...